# "mehr als unschön"?

Tags: adjective, comparison

…oder doch eher

> "weniger als unschön"

Es geht um die Steigerung eines negativ belegten Adjektivs.

Folgt man der klassischen Anatomie einer Steigerung, wäre *"mehr als"* richtig. Folgt man der Logik, wäre es *"weniger als"*.

Was ist korrekt?

Comment: Hat Logik jetzt einen _twitter account_ ? Aber mal Spaß beiseite. Ich glaube nicht, dass in der Logik es müsste hier "weniger als" heißen ableitbar ist. Aber auch das erscheint sicher der Allgemeinheit _unlogisch_ .

Comment: Eine Steigerung kann positiv wie negativ sein. Doppelt so schlecht wird ja auch nicht plötzlich gut. Mathematisch ausgedrückt: -1*2 ergibt -2 und nicht +2 ;-)

Comment: `(-2)*(1/2)*(1) = weniger(-2) als kaum(1/2) schön(1)` Naja...

Answer (score 10):

> Das ist mehr als unschön.

ist die richtige Wahl, um die Häßlichkeit noch zu steigern.

Es wird sogar sehr oft mit negativ gemeinten Worten verwendet.

> Ist es dir auch warm genug?
>
> Es ist mehr als warm hier.

Dann ist es dem zweiten Sprecher zu warm, das Wort "warm" ist also aus seiner Sicht negativ.

> Sie ist mehr als zufrieden mit ihrem neuen Computer.

ist aber positiv gemeint.

Comment: +1 Sag doch einfach _mehr als unschön_ ist noch _unschöner_ als _unschön_. Bei deinem Satz muss man ja Nachdenken.

Comment: @bernd Jetzt alles eindeutig?

Comment: @thei _Es ist mehr als warm_ würde ich nicht unbedingt als Kritik einstufen, könnte auch als reine Feststellung, dass es dem Sprecher zu warm ist, aufgefasst werden.

Comment: @bernd "zu warm" bedeutet, dass warm hier als negativ gesehen wird.

Comment: `F: Ist die Suppe schön heiß?` - `A: [Ja.] Sie ist mehr als blos warm!`. Bei manchen Adjektiven stimme ich dem Fragesteller aber zu, da0 die Steigerung mit 'mehr' seltsam klingt: `Der Bus ist mehr als nur langsam.` oder `Die Kasse ist mehr als fast leer.` wird sporadisch verwendet, aber wirkt schräg.

Comment: @user: "Die Kasse ist mehr als fast leer" würde ich persönlich _nie_ sagen; "fast leer" ist schon die maximale Steigung vor "leer". Ich denke da an ["Weniger ist leer"](http://www.weniger-ist-leer.de/) ...

Comment: Es geht nicht um "warm", sondern um "kalt". Sind es mehr oder weniger als -20 Grad, wenn es -25 sind?

Comment: Ich sage "mehr als unschön" ist falsch, es sei denn, der Sprecher will die Aussage machen, dass es se doch gar nicht so unschön sei, wie er zuerst dachte.

Comment: @markus: Das ist eine übliche Konstruktion. Es ist mehr als naiv, wenn du glaubst, dass das mehr als ungewöhnlich ist, diesem Konstrukt zu begegnen. Und es heißt ganz sicher niemals, dass es schöner ist als unschön. (Mir scheint, das ist schon wieder ein Fall, wo einige verwechseln, was es bedeutet, und was es bedeuten sollte.)

Comment: @thei: Nur weil die Mehrheit es so benutzt (= übliche Konstruktion), bedeutet das nicht, dass die Konstruktion richtig ist.

Comment: @markus: Bitte schreib einfach eine eigene Antwort, wo du begründest, warum das falsch ist. Kleiner Tipp für die Analyse: Derartige Konstruktionen kommen ähnlich wie Litotes-Formulierungen von sozialen Feinheiten der Sprache.

Answer (score 1):

Das Tapetenmuster ist besonders scheußlich.

Das Glas ist nicht nur fast leer – es ist leer. Es ist gewiss nicht mehr leer als eben, auch nicht leerer als eben, weil *leer* absolut ist. Es ist weniger voll.

Der Bus ist bergab schon langsam – bergauf ist er langsamer als eben noch – langsamer als langsam ist schon nicht richtig – 'mehr langsam als langsam' ist zudem hässlich.

Immer wenn es um abzählbare Mengen geht, auch bei messbaren Größen, wirkt ein 'mehr weniger' schräg.

> Die Sprintstrecke der Frauen ist mehr kurz als die der Männer.

Nein. "Die Sprintstrecke der Frauen ist kürzer noch als die der Männer".

Bei

> Heute war es mehr als −20 °C

wird das Problem besonders deutlich. Mit einem Thermometer vor Augen ist das `mehr` weiter oben verortet. Mehr Temperatur bedeutet etwa −15 °C, mehr kalt aber −25 °C. Darf man aber "mehr kalt" sagen?

Besser ist es zu sagen, es sei kälter als oder wärmer als soundsoviel Grad.

Die Aussage

> mehr als unschön

ruft die Frage hervor *mehr was? mehr Licht*? Es kann *mehr schön als unschön* gemeint sein, aber das würde niemand sagen. *Mehr unschön als unschön* ist eine unschöne Konstruktion – mehr noch: Es ist die unschönste Formulierung, die überhaupt denkbar ist, eine Steigerung des Mangels an Schönheit.

Auch sagbar ist, dass darin noch weniger Schönheit sei als wenig.

> Unschöner als unschön

lässt keinen Zweifel offen, ob es nun wahrlich zum Gipfel der Scheußlichkeiten strebt, ins tiefe Tal der Hässlichkeit, aber schön ist auch dieser Ausdruck nicht. Man könnte sagen, in seiner eigenen Unschönheit zeigt die Konstruktion eine Fratze, die das, was sie beschreiben will, sprachlich verdoppelt, und durch die Dissonanz, die sie im Hirn des Lesers oder Hörers erzeugt, wird das Bezeichnete aufs trefflichste bezeichnet.

Unschön bezeichnet aber den ganzen Bereich jenseits der Schönheit, sowie auch alles, was weniger warm als lau ist, kalt ist – sei es nun etwas kalt oder extrem kalt. Null Kelvin ist auch kalt. Kälter als kalt gibt es also nicht, und unschöner als unschön gibt es auch nicht.

Ergo gibt es auch nicht `mehr als unschön`, sofern man damit `besonders unschön` ausdrücken will.

Der Fahrplan für den aufmerksamen Sprachfreund mag also lauten:

- Im passiven Sprachsatz ergibt sich die Bedeutung aus dem Kontext, oder es ist die Steigerung des Mangels einer Eigenschaft gemeint, oder man fragt eben nach.
- In den aktiven Sprachschatz nimmt man derlei nicht auf, sondern sucht sich aus den mannigfachen Ausdrucksmöglichkeiten Formulierungen, die schöner sind.

Comment: In der Umgangssprache ist und bleibt "mehr als unschön" üblich, und ich glaube nicht, dass es falsch verstanden wird. Unschön finde ich persönlich die Formulierung auch nicht, in gehobenem Deutsch hat sie aber meiner Meinung nach nichts zu suchen.

Comment: Aber Hochdeutsch ist doch, was wir - soweit nicht anders gefordert - empfehlen. Du siehst ja, dass es nicht klar verständlich ist an den Reaktionen hier.

Comment: "Was einen gefälligen, wohlgeformten Satz bilden, um das Missbildete darzustellen?" finde ich mehr als unschön, ja geradezu mißlungen und unverständlich.

Comment: @Matthias: Ich weiß nicht ob mir da ein Wort oder Satzteile entgangen sind - der Satz macht so gar keinen Sinn! Da mir nicht mehr einfällt was ich sagen wollte habe ich ihn gelöscht. Danke für den Hinweis.

Answer (score 1):

> mehr als unschön

bezieht sich auf die Steigerung der Eigenschaft "unschön".

> weniger als unschön

bezieht sich auf einen geringeren Wert, ein geringeres Ansehen.

Die Wissenschaft "Logik" beschreibt die grundlegendsten Gesetzmäßigkeiten unserer Welt. Die Regeln einer Sprache sind Konventionen, also sollte man hier nicht von Logik sprechen. ;-)

Die Formulierung "weniger als unschön" wirkt verwirrend, weil man nicht sofort erkennt, ob es um die Minderung einer Eigenschaft oder eines Wertes geht.

Answer (score -1):

- am schönsten
- schöner
- schön
- unschön
- unschöner
- am unschönsten

gegen oben = schöner (mehr an Schönheit)
gegen unten = unschöner (weniger an Schönheit)

"Mehr als unschön" liegt also höher in der Hierarchie und bedeutet darum irgendwas zwischen unschön und am schönsten.

Die häufige Benutzung einer Konstruktion, macht diese nicht korrekt.

Comment: Deine Behautung, dass "Mehr als unschön" höher in der Hierarchie liegt und darum irgendwas zwischen unschön und am schönsten bedeutet, ist _falsch_. Ich kenne niemanden, der dies so verstehen würde, aber viele, die "mehr als unschön" und ähnliche Wendungen (mit leicht ironischem Unterton) benutzen, und die praktisch immer richtig verstanden werden.

Comment: +1 - vielleicht liegt es ja an meinem Programmiererhintergrund, daß ich das logisch finde.

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt: Jetzt kennst du bereits zwei ;)

Comment: @markus: Wenn ich, mit leicht abfälligem Tonfall und Betonung auf _mehr_, sagen würde, dass etwas _mehr als unschön_ ist, würdest Du wirklich verstehen, dass ich's nicht ganz so hässlich finde?

Comment: Ich würde dich verstehen... eventuell auch ohne nonverbale Komponente. Ich sage ja nicht, dass es nicht so gebraucht wird, ich sage nur, es sei herausragend unlogisch.

Comment: @markus: Wenn Du mich verstehen würdest, dann verstehe ich nicht, warum Du "bedeutet darum irgendwas zwischen unschön und am schönsten" schreibst.

Comment: Ich würde dich verstehen, weil ich weiss, dass es so gebraucht wird, was aber noch lange nicht heisst, dass ich das auch so brauchen würde. Täte ich niemals!

Comment: @markus: Habe gerade Deinen Kommentar hier gefunden. Nur um Missverständnissen vorzubeugen: Ich habe hier keine Minuspunkte verteilt. (Noch ein inhaltlicher Kommentar: Sprache ist oft herausragend unlogisch; das macht die Formulierung noch lange nicht falsch.)

Comment: Nach der Logik müsste ich "mehr Schulden" machen, denn das führt ja dann zu weniger Schulden, oder? Das "mehr" bezieht sich ja auf die Richtung, in die es geht. "Mehr unschön" ist "unschöner", "Mehr schön" ist "schöner".